# Can't notify from Orion context Broker v2 to Cepheus context broker v1

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, complex-event-processing

Despite of set attrsFormtat to legacy it's not working, I get Missing parameter: updateAction

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

EDITED: I try it in a million ways and i can't handle this always getting the same error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot see the error message in the snapshoot of your question post... could your question post in order to include the error you are getting, please? In addition, please state which Orion version are you using (the output to `contextBroker --version` provides this information). Thx!

Comment: fgalan info actualizada.

Comment: It seems that Cepheus is the one reporting "Missing updateAction" error. Let's see if some Cepheus expert can clarify about what is the cause of that problem.

Comment: Thanks fgalan, I'm trying to find some cepheus expert but I dont know where to find them. Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.fiware.org/contact-us/

Comment: Yes it is, waiting for the answer. Thnks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154159/discussion-between-pablog1108-and-fgalan).

Comment: Well Im using the stand alone version of Cepheus Broker, May I use the docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in Cepheus Broker but I have a bit of experience playing with Cepheus CEP and Orion Context Broker in FIWARE ecosystem, maybe I can be useful.

According to the official [documentation](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/fiware-cepheus/blob/master/doc/broker/index.md#introduction) of CEP, you should be deploying Cepheus Broker before Orion Context Broker instead after. I know that both speak the same NGSI API so it should be the same, but I am not completely sure about that. Any particular reason why you are deploying these components in that order?

[image]

I make a little experiment using official Docker images of Cepheus Broker and Orion context Broker, creating context subscriptions through v1 and v2 Orion APIs. The same error as you on Cepheus Broker logs.

Then I proved with [this](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/scripts/accumulator-server.py) little app made by Fiware fellows, that you can use for debbuging NGSI context subscriptions. I tried with v1 and v2 subscriptions, with legacy and no legacy in v2 and any of this produces a "updateAction" field in the request. Then I realized that as far as I know, within the NGSI API methods the only service that receives the updateAction parameter is the [updateContext](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv1/index.html#update-context-elements) service.

May be Cepheus can not connect with Orion Context Broker through Context Subscription mechanism. Maybe he's waiting for a context update instead a context change notification.

Sorry for not being of more help.

Regards!

Comment: thanks Emiliano, Was my fault. I have to include the orion broker port in the start of cepheus cep.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make Orion send a `notifyContext` request to the `updateContext` endpoint of Cepheus CEP. This cannot work as an `updateContext` request is expected to contain an `updateAction` field in the payload according to the NGSI v1 protocol.

Cepheus CEP expects notifications from subscriptions to be done to its `notifyContext` endpoint.

Moreover Cepheus CEP will send its own subscription requests to Orion when properly setup (you must declare Orion as a provider in the CEP configuration). It will ask Orion to send back notification to the correct endpoint.

Finaly, you cannot make the subscription on behalf of Cepheus CEP like you are trying to do: Cepheus CEP will only accepts notifications for the subscriptions it made itself because it validates the subscription ids of all notification it receives.